# SQL: JOIN two tables with distinct rows from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

This might be a very simple problem but I can't seem to get my head around this since last night.

I have 3 tables

```
VirtualLicense
VirtualLicenseId    ProductName
-----------------------------------
1           Transaction
2           Query
3           Transaction


Product
ProductId   Name
---------------------------
1           Transaction
2           Query


License
LicenseId   ExpiryDate  ProductId
-----------------------------------------
1           14/07/2013  1
2           13/07/2013  1
3           13/07/2013  2
4           14/07/2013  2
```

The VirtualLicense and License are joined using ProductName and ProductId mapping using the Product table.

I want to get combination of VirtualLicenseId and LicenseId, where I can basically assign the VirtualLicenseId to a LicenseId. Once a licenseid is assigned to a VirtualLicenseId, it should not be available for the following VirtualLicenseIds. Also, I want that the licenseid for which the expirydate is nearer(smaller) should be assigned first.

So, the result for my example data set should be

```
VirtualLicenseId    LicenseId
---------------------------------
1                   2
2                   3
3                   1
```

I do not want to loop over any of the tables for this. 
I hope my problem is clear from my description and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- In first CTE - assign rankings for VirtualLicenses within the Product groups.
- In second CTE - assign rankings for Licensce within the Product groups (order by exp. date)
- And at the end just join the two subqueries on productID and ranking.

---

```
WITH CTE_VL AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY vl.VirtualLicenseId ASC) RN
    FROM dbo.VirtualLicense vl
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Product p ON vl.ProductName = p.Name
)
,CTE_License AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY ExpiryDate ASC) RN
    FROM dbo.License 
)
SELECT VirtualLicenseId, LicenseId 
FROM CTE_VL vl
LEFT JOIN CTE_License l ON vl.ProductId = l.ProductID AND vl.RN = l.RN
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6ed8/1)**